# Ruby on rails paths and routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the hang of basic Rails routing.
I have a model called page which I generated with a scaffold.
I have added a method called addchild which I would like to access through

```
'pages/addchild/:id'
```

So far so good.  However, I want to set up a link to this method like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Add child page', addchild_page_path(page) %>
```

Passing the ID of the current page as a parameter.

When I load my index view (where the link is), I get the following message:

```
undefined local variable or method `addchild_page_path' for    #<ActionView::Base:0xb67797d0>
```

Have I misunderstood how the path/link_to method works?

My routes file looks like this:

```
  map.resources :pages
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a route to it to be able to use the named path methods.

Since you mentioned you used scaffolding, you probably have the route setup as a resource, so all that you need to do is add the method:

```
map.resources :pages, :member => {:addchild => :get}
```

Would give you an `addchild_pages_path` (and the actual created path would look like `/pages/:id/addchild`

You then use it like this: `addchild_pages_path page`, don't call the `id` method directly since it is not resourceful (you won't use the `to_param` in the page class, which you might want to do later).

If you really want the url to show up as `/pages/addchild/:id` (which I don't recommend) you can add

```
map.addchild_page "/pages/addchild/:id", :controller => :pages, :method => :addchild
```

before the `map.resources :pages` row in your routes.rb, and then use the path method as above.

Comment: Thanks.
Yes, I wanted the url formatted the default way, I just mistyped it.